# Do I need to watch the original Devilman anime before I watch Crybaby?

Tags: devilman, devilman-crybaby

I was looking around on Netflix and I thought that Devilman Crybaby looked interesting. I looked it up and there's a 39 episode Devilman anime. Do I need to watch that before I watch Crybaby?